# close dialog javascript on different page

Tags: javascript, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

can I close the dialog javascript after submited  the data in the dialog( form in the dialog was load on different page),. 
sory my english is bad, this is the script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a#href').live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr("href")
            var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title")
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            //var $dialog = $(window.parent.document.getElementById('modal')) 
            .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
            //.html(page)
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 550,
                width: 700,
                title: pagetitle

                    });
                $dialog.dialog('open');


                });

 });
```

html :

```
<a id="href" title="Form Upload Dokumen BAUK / BAUF" href="upload_bauk_r2b.php?project_id=<?php echo $project_id; ?>"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iFrame is coming from the same domain, what I assume since you only use a filename and not a whole domain to reference `upload_bauk_r2b.php`, then it should be possible to access the iFrame from the parent document (where your current script lies within).

So you could programatically (with Javascript) produce a "close"-Button in the iFrame and then bind the destruction of the modal popup to that close-Button. I am not expert when it comes to jQuery, but I guess you would bind the event similarly as you bound the 'click'-Event on that -Link.

Another hint: Why using iFrames anyway? Couldn't you just load the content of that modal popup dynamically over AJAX?

Comment: thx,
I follow on this blog http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/18/loading-a-page-into-a-dialog/ 

with ajax how i can make a modal popup ?